Echarts grid align data label with x axis
This chart works fine for all positive value when yieldGap is above zero, but alignment is not working when there is negative value in yieldGap. Is there any way to align market and airline value with it's label?
Normal aligned view

View when negative value is in the chart

Reproduceable demo
